# Access private data item from php object

Tags: php, object

I have been working on listing object and did not find a way to access private data items in object. What I'm trying to do is to access event date inside special_keys object.  The var_dump of object is below:

```
object(MyListing\Src\Listing)#3176 (9) {
  ["data":"MyListing\Src\Listing":private]=>
  object(WP_Post)#3167 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(38)
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-12 16:46:24"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-12 16:46:24"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(38) "This is just a test event for one day."
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(18) "Another test event"
    ["post_excerpt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["comment_status"]=>
    string(4) "open"
    ["ping_status"]=>
    string(6) "closed"
    ["post_password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_name"]=>
    string(18) "another-test-event"
    ["to_ping"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pinged"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_modified"]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-13 05:51:40"
    ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-13 05:51:40"
    ["post_content_filtered"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["guid"]=>
    string(52) "http://34.84.92.224/?post_type=job_listing&#038;p=38"
    ["menu_order"]=>
    int(0)
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(11) "job_listing"
    ["post_mime_type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["comment_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  ["categories":"MyListing\Src\Listing":private]=>
  NULL
  ["special_keys":"MyListing\Src\Listing":private]=>
  array(17) {
    [":id"]=>
    int(38)
    [":url"]=>
    string(47) "http://34.84.92.224/listing/another-test-event/"
    [":lat"]=>
    NULL
    [":lng"]=>
    NULL
    [":date"]=>
    string(16) "October 12, 2020"
    [":rawdate"]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-12 16:46:24"
    [":last-modified"]=>
    string(16) "October 13, 2020"
    [":authid"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [":authname"]=>
    string(10) "Test Admin"
    [":authlogin"]=>
    string(5) "fixer"
    [":currentuserid"]=>
    int(2)
    [":currentusername"]=>
    string(10) "Test Admin"
    [":currentuserlogin"]=>
    string(5) "fixer"
    [":reviews-mode"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [":reviews-average"]=>
    object(Closure)#3189 (1) {
      ["this"]=>
      *RECURSION*
    }
    [":reviews-count"]=>
    object(Closure)#3192 (1) {
      ["this"]=>
      *RECURSION*
    }
    [":reviews-stars"]=>
    object(Closure)#3190 (1) {
      ["this"]=>
      *RECURSION*
    }
  } }
```

I have tried to accessed data and it shows the data object.

```
var_dump($field->listing->get_data());
```

But when I try to get special keys object like above it is not working.

```
var_dump($field->listing->get_special_keys());
```

Comment: You would normally have a method in the class which would allow access to private data if there is any intention of you being able to use these values.

Comment: The entire point of making something private in a class is that it's private! So that's probably intentional on the part of the person who programmed this class. Why do you think you need access to this data? Because the person who programmed it obviously thought you didn't - unless, as Nigel says above, they provided a specific function elsewhere in the class that you can use to get access to it.

Comment: @ADyson now I got the point. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

However, there are situations, for example during testing, where it is necessary to access private properties of a class without changing them.
This is possible with the [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflection.php). A simple example:

```
class test{
  private $val;
  public function __construct($val){
    $this->val = $val;
  }
}
$obj = new test('current_Value');

$rc = new ReflectionClass($obj);
$property = $rc->getProperty('val');
$property->setAccessible(true);
$value =  $property->getValue($obj);
echo $value;  //current_Value
```